# How to show the "Not Found" route in react while using a route container?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The "Not Found" route is not showing for me using react router 5.1.

index.js:

```
function AuthedContainer() {
  const { loading, token, name, refreshError } = useCheckAccessToken();

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <LoadingOverlay loadingStatus={loading} />
      <NavBar name={name} />
      {isAllowed(userPermissions, ["view_results"]) && (
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/table" component={Table} token={token} />
      )}
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route exact component={AuthedContainer} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have tried placing the "Not Found" route within the route const, but that did not work as well.

```
const routes = (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route exact component={AuthedContainer} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I found out that the "Not Found" route should be directly within the switch component, so I tried refactoring such that all my routes including the authed ones are within the same switch component. However, I do not want the `useCheckAccessToken()` hook to be called when I am on the `/login` route.

Can anyone advise on how I can get the "Not Found" route to work without calling the authed hook when not logged in? (if there is a token, it means you are logged in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having all my routes in 1 switch, and then having different layouts for authorised routes.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {pages.map(
          (
            {
              exact,
              path,
              component: Component,
              layout: Layout,
              requiredPermissions
            },
            index
          ) => (
            <Route
              key={index}
              exact={exact}
              path={path}
              render={props => (
                <Layout requiredPermissions={requiredPermissions}>
                  <Component {...props} />
                </Layout>
              )}
            />
          )
        )}
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Each page can be defined like so:

```
export const pages = [
  // Public pages
  {
    exact: true,
    path: routes.login,
    component: LoginPage,
    layout: PublicLayout,
    requiredPermissions: []
  },
  // Authenticated pages
  {
    exact: true,
    path: routes.dashboard,
    component: Dashboard,
    layout: AuthedLayout,
    requiredPermissions: []
  },
...
```

The token handling would be handled in "AuthedLayout":

```
export default function AuthedLayout(props) {
  const { loading, token, name, refreshError } = useCheckAccessToken();
  const userPermissions = GetUserPermissions(token);

  return !refreshError ? (
      <Fragment>
        <LoadingOverlay loadingStatus={loading} />
        <NavBar name={name} />
        <props.children.type token={token} userPermissions={userPermissions} />
      </Fragment>
  ) : !(!loading && token && name && !refreshError) ? (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  ) : (
    "Unhandled Exception."
  );
}
```

Hope these helped someone.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function AuthedContainer() {
  const { loading, token, name, refreshError } = useCheckAccessToken();

  if(token){
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <LoadingOverlay loadingStatus={loading} />
        <NavBar name={name} />
        {isAllowed(userPermissions, ["view_results"]) && (
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/table" component={Table} token={token} />
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }else{
    <NotFound/>
  }
```

Comment: This will not work because if the user is authenticated and tries to visit an invalid URL, the "Not Found" route will not show up.